# Can anyone tell me why my cylinder is not in a straight line when I zoom out?

Tags: rendering, smooth

[image]

Here is the image of the cylinder; you can see there's a tearing when you see the cylinder clearly. What is the solution to make it smooth? Is it vsync? But it's Blender, not a game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Make Viewport Anti-Aliasing higher

[image]

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer when the other one is clearly right and this is just a way to make it look prettier/smoother while still not straight.

Comment: Because the asker require fix the tearing in his question.

Answer (score 6):

This is expected. The default viewport is look at the scene with a **perspective** projection, meaning that the parts of the cylinder at different heights will look different relative to the camera.

If you want objects to be perfectly straight, you can change the viewport to an **orthographic** perspective with Numpad 5 or the bottom button on top right of the viewport.